# What in the world is wrong with my Ubuntu Touch app?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, mir

I'm working on an Ubuntu Touch app that works flawlessly with `qmlscene`. However, when I attempt to run it on an actual device, I get a bunch of dots all over the portion of the screen dedicated to the app (the notification bar along the top is unaffected as well as the launcher when I swipe from the left edge). I'd absolutely love to post a screenshot but `mirscreencast` isn't working either.

The name of the application is "2buntu" and it is available for installation in the app store. The source code is viewable here: https://github.com/2buntu/2buntu-Ubuntu-Touch-App.

#### Technical Details:

- Development Machine:

  - Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
  - All updates installed, including everything from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
  - A working kit for armhf-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-utopic in Qt Creator
- Testing Device

  - Nexus 5 with MultiROM
  - Ubuntu Touch 14.10 (r245)
  - Developer mode enabled and tested with `adb shell`

If anyone can shed even the slightest bit of light on what I've done wrong, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your .desktop is hard-coded to look for your QML files in /usr/share/twobuntu-app.  Instead, make your Exec line:

```
qmlscene $@ twobuntu-app.qml
```